# junit.framework.AssertionFailedError

Tags: android, sqlite, junit

I get error of this:

> junit.framework.AssertionFailedError at
>   com.example.sirivan.myfirstapp.test.TestDb.testCreateDb(TestDb.java:22)

**TestDb.java**

```
public class TestDb extends AndroidTestCase {
    public static final String LOG_TAG = TestDb.class.getSimpleName();

    public void testCreateDb() throws Throwable{
        assertTrue(mContext.deleteDatabase(WeatherDbHelper.DATABASE_NAME));
        SQLiteDatabase db = new WeatherDbHelper(
            this.mContext).getWritableDatabase();
            assertEquals(true, db.isOpen());
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Then one of your assertions has failed... Which ever one is at line 22

Comment: assertTrue(mContext.deleteDatabase(WeatherDbHelper.DATABASE_NAME));

Answer (score 0):

Following the documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#deleteDatabase(java.lang.String)

> Returns true if the database was successfully deleted; else false.

Comment: how should i code this? im kinda confuse...sorry im kinda new in android development

Comment: for example, did you create the database before to delete it? If you are not use to develop in Android, in my opinion, Android tests are more dificult than an application development. So get experience developing an application and then build your tests